# How to allow string, integer, and boolean input in a macro definition

Tags: c, gcc, macros, c-preprocessor

I have a macro where I need it to accept input from strings, integers and boolean

Currently I get error C4047 function': `'char *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'`

How can I check if the argument is a string, integer or boolean and apply each according to its correct form?

My table:

```
Strings = {
  Apply = {"successfully applied", true, 150, "OK" },
  Check = {"check done", 100, false },
  Test  = {"test completed", "Fail", 1, true }
};
```

My code:

```
#define lua_get_test(L, tbl, ...) do { \
    lua_getfield(L, lua_gettop(L), tbl); \
    if (lua_istable(L, lua_gettop(L))) \
    { \
        int n = (int)lua_rawlen(L, lua_gettop(L)); \
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) { \
            lua_rawgeti(L, lua_gettop(L), i); \
            if (lua_isstring(L, lua_gettop(L))) \
                strcpy(__VA_ARGS__, lua_tostring(L, lua_gettop(L))); \
            else if(lua_isboolean(L, lua_gettop(L))) \
                __VA_ARGS__ = lua_toboolean(L, lua_gettop(L)); \
            else if(lua_isinteger(L, lua_gettop(L))) \
                __VA_ARGS__ = (int)lua_tointeger(L, lua_gettop(L)); \
            else \
                continue; \
            lua_pop(L, 1); \
        } \
    } \
    lua_pop(L, 1); \
} while(false)

void read_table(void) {
    lua_State *L;
    L = luaL_newstate();
    luaL_openlibs(L);

    if (luaL_loadfile(L, "table.lua") || lua_pcall(L, 0, 0, 0))
    {
        ShowError("Error reading 'table.lua'\n");
        return;
    }

    lua_getglobal(L, "Strings");
    lua_get_test(L, "Apply", var_string, var_bool, var_int, var_string);
    lua_get_test(L, "Check", var_string, var_int, var_bool);
    lua_get_test(L, "Test", var_string, var_string, var_int, var_bool);

    lua_close(L);
    printf("Read Table complete.\n");

}
```

Is there anything to be done to avoid these errors?

Comment: Macros only deal with text and are expanded before any language analysis. So, there is absolutely no way to find out a language type of a macro argument. Switch to c++.

Comment: @Serge There is a C way: Have the macro use `_Generic` and let `_Generic` call the steered code.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica How could I combine _Generic with multiple arguments, could you give me an example?

Comment: `_Generic` can not help if the number of parameters doesn't have a fixed size, that's too complex for the preprocessor. Consider using a variadic function a la `printf` specifying the types in a first argument. Another option is a lightweight json parser, take a look to this one: https://zserge.com/jsmn/

Comment: @DavidRanieri OP's steering is based on a fixed count out parameters: `z, name`. `_Generic` can work here, yet functionality of code like `is_string(z, name)` is too fuzzy - needs details.  All of OP's 3 examples use `zindex`, _some_string_.

Comment: @chux `z, name` are fixed but they are followed by an unspecified number of parameters ... I don't see how `_Generic` can help in this case.

Comment: Perhaps OP will post more sample details of the coding goal to make it worth trying to solve.

Comment: @DavidRanieri  Added an example with known functions other than my custom functions

Comment: I do not super understand. You would write a variadic function, why are you using a macro. I do not understand how `__VA_ARGS__ =` with multiple arguments is supposed to work? Please add missisng `#include` to your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That doesn't look like a macro, you would use a normal variadic function.

```
void lua_get_test(lua_State *L, char *tbl, ...) {}
    va_list va;
    va_start(va, tbl);
    lua_getfield(L, lua_gettop(L), tbl);
    if (lua_istable(L, lua_gettop(L))) {
        int n = (int)lua_rawlen(L, lua_gettop(L));
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            lua_rawgeti(L, lua_gettop(L), i);
            if (lua_isstring(L, lua_gettop(L))) {
                char *var = va_arg(va, char *);
                strcpy(var, lua_tostring(L, lua_gettop(L))); \
            } else if(lua_isboolean(L, lua_gettop(L))) {
                bool *var = va_arg(va, bool *);
                *var = lua_toboolean(L, lua_gettop(L));
            } else if(lua_isinteger(L, lua_gettop(L))) {
                int *var = va_arg(va, int *);
                *var = (int)lua_tointeger(L, lua_gettop(L));
            } else {
                continue;
            }
            lua_pop(L, 1);
        }
    }
    lua_pop(L, 1);
    va_end(va);
}

void read_table(void) {
    lua_State *L;
    L = luaL_newstate();
    luaL_openlibs(L);

    if (luaL_loadfile(L, "table.lua") || lua_pcall(L, 0, 0, 0))
    {
        ShowError("Error reading 'table.lua'\n");
        return;
    }

    lua_getglobal(L, "Strings");
    lua_get_test(L, "Apply", var_string, &var_bool, &var_int, var_string);
    lua_get_test(L, "Check", var_string, &var_int, &var_bool);
    lua_get_test(L, "Test", var_string, var_string, &var_int, &var_bool);

    lua_close(L);
    printf("Read Table complete.\n");
}
```

If you want argument type checking, consider using C++ with templates.

> How to allow string, integer, and boolean input in a macro definition

You can't. Macro takes *tokens*. The types of arguments are irrelevent, if the arguments are variables is also irrelevant. You can pass any text as macro argument.

```
#define somemacro(...)
somemacro(you can write almost anything here and it will be ignored)
```

> How can I check if the argument is a string, integer or boolean and apply each according to its correct form?

Checking is really hard in C, consider C++ with templates. You would create an enum of possible types and apply _Generic on the argument to translate it to enum values and then compare the enum values of the type. Usually in C, what you do is create multiple function for every type. **Just like** `lua_tointeger` `lua_toboolean` and `lua_tostring` - one function for every type. And then you have an iterator `lua_rawgeti` to iterate over abstract variables. C has no function overloading. That's in C++. In C you can:

```
enum types {
    TYPE_BOOL,
    TYPE_INT,
    TYPE_CHARP,
};

#define VAR_TO_TYPE(arg) _Generic((arg) \
    , bool: TYPE_BOOL \
    , int: TYPE_INT \
    , char *: TYPE_CHARP \
    )

bool check_type_of_arg(enum types type, enum types shouldbetype) {
    return type == shouldbetype;
}

#define check_type_of_arg(arg, shouldbetype)  check_type_of_arg(VAR_TO_TYPE(arg), shouldbetype)

int main() {
    check_type_of_arg(1, TYPE_INT);
}
```

You would then apply the process for each macro argument to create an array of enum values of types of every argument and then compare.

```
enum types {
    TYPE_NONE,
    TYPE_BOOL,
    TYPE_INT,
    TYPE_CHARP,
    TYPE_INTP,
    TYPE_BOOLP,
};

#define VAR_TO_TYPE(arg) _Generic((arg) \
    , bool: TYPE_BOOL \
    , int: TYPE_INT \
    , char *: TYPE_CHARP \
    , int *: TYPE_INTP \
    , bool *: TYPE_BOOLP \
    )
    
#define APPLYFOREACHJOINCOMMA_1(f,a)  f(a)
#define APPLYFOREACHJOINCOMMA_2(f,a,...)  f(a), APPLYFOREACHJOINCOMMA_1(f,__VA_ARGS__)
#define APPLYFOREACHJOINCOMMA_3(f,a,...)  f(a), APPLYFOREACHJOINCOMMA_2(f,__VA_ARGS__)
#define APPLYFOREACHJOINCOMMA_4(f,a,...)  f(a), APPLYFOREACHJOINCOMMA_3(f,__VA_ARGS__)
#define APPLYFOREACHJOINCOMMA_N(_4,_3,_2,_1,N,...)  APPLYFOREACHJOINCOMMA_##N
#define APPLYFOREACHJOINCOMMA(f, ...)  APPLYFOREACHJOINCOMMA_N(__VA_ARGS__,_4,_3,_2,_1)(f,__VA_ARGS__)

void lua_get_test(const enum types *vartypes, lua_State *L, char *tbl, ...) {}
    va_list va;
    va_start(va, tbl);
    const enum types *itypes = vartypes;
    lua_getfield(L, lua_gettop(L), tbl);
    if (lua_istable(L, lua_gettop(L))) {
        int n = (int)lua_rawlen(L, lua_gettop(L));
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            lua_rawgeti(L, lua_gettop(L), i);
            if (lua_isstring(L, lua_gettop(L))) {
                if (*itypes++ != TYPE_CHARP) { /* error - wrong argument type */ }
                char *var = va_arg(va, char *);
                strcpy(var, lua_tostring(L, lua_gettop(L))); \
            } else if(lua_isboolean(L, lua_gettop(L))) {
                if (*itypes++ != TYPE_BOOLP) { /* error - wrong argument type */ }
                bool *var = va_arg(va, bool *);
                *var = lua_toboolean(L, lua_gettop(L));
            } else if(lua_isinteger(L, lua_gettop(L))) {
                if (*itypes++ != TYPE_INTP) { /* error - wrong argument type */ }
                int *var = va_arg(va, int *);
                *var = (int)lua_tointeger(L, lua_gettop(L));
            } else {
                continue;
            }
            lua_pop(L, 1);
        }
    }
    lua_pop(L, 1);
    va_end(va);
}

#define lua_get_test(L, tbl, ...)  lua_get_test( \
    /* Create array compound literal of enum types of arguments */ \
    (const enum types[]){ \
        APPLYFOREACHJOINCOMMA(VAR_TO_TYPE_COMMA, __VA_ARGS__), \
        /* use sentinel value to handle wrong number of arguments */ \
        TYPE_NONE, \
    },
    L, tbl, __VA_ARGS__ )
```

Note that you can't compare type of argument in a macro. Macro has no variables, has no types. The above code generates an array of types representation in a macro - then the comparison and code is then in normal code. Prefer to keep macros usage to minimum.